# How to select DataFrame columns for plotting in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python DataFrame from Pandas

```
waitEvent   instance    snapDate    gc cr block 3-way   gc current block 3-way  log file sync
```

Every time I construct this DataFrame, the number and name of columns after the snapDate are different.

I would need to construct a new DataFrame by selecting `snapDate` as the indexcolumn but the remaining columns should be dynamically selected for plotting any ideas. How can I achieve this?

for the `df` above, I should always select the `snapDate` column and all the columns 
after the `snapDate` column

The number and name of the columns after the snapDate column will vary.

My objective is to do

```
df[snapDate,col1,col2,col3].plot()
df[snapDate,col7,col8].plot()
..
```

I want to create a plot from the DataFrame by always picking the SnapDate column and the remaining columns which depending on the DataFrame could be 2 or 3 or 4 etc.

Comment: are you sure you question is correclty formatted? I do not see the data. You want basically to create a plot function, correct?

Comment: Will snapDate always be the 3rd column? In that case, you can select the columns after it with :  `df.iloc[:,2:]`

Comment: Hi Colonel data doesn't matter for this example i guess.I can post some sample data if required.Stellasia i want to include snapDate column and all the columns after snapDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas.Index.get_loc) to get the index position of the column of interest and then use this to index your df:

```
In [374]:
cols = ['waitEvent','instance','snapDate','gc cr block 3-way','gc current block 3-way','log file sync']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
df

Out[374]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [waitEvent, instance, snapDate, gc cr block 3-way, gc current block 3-way, log file sync]
Index: []

In [378]:    
snapDateIdx = df.columns.get_loc('snapDate')
snapDateIdx

Out[378]:
2

In [379]:
df.ix[:,snapDateIdx:]

Out[379]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [snapDate, gc cr block 3-way, gc current block 3-way, log file sync]
Index: []
```